# Azure Graph, get type by PrincipalId (ObjectId)

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I have a list of PrincipalId (user, groups, application) and I would like to have information about.

But as I don't know the type, I do not know what endpoint query ? /users or /groups or /applications

Is it a way to ask Graph what is the type of the ObjectId ? I see nothing on the documentation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the Microsoft Graph API - [directoryObject: getByIds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryobject-getbyids?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

Sample:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/getByIds

{
    "ids": [
        "202b56d4-c7bc-4fa5-910d-20c3971a84b6",
        "a0014fd5-0ced-4df5-b9e6-ae98a9f67d4d",
        "8f9f95e2-0b38-4521-83e5-c8e8fea0f5a1"
    ]
}
```

[image]

Or if you want to use the deprecated [Azure AD Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/api-catalog)(I recommend you to use Microsoft Graph), you could use the API below.

```
POST https://graph.windows.net/<tenant-id>/getObjectsByObjectIds?api-version=1.6 

{
    "objectIds": ["202b56d4-c7bc-4fa5-910d-20c3971a84b6", "a0014fd5-0ced-4df5-b9e6-ae98a9f67d4d", "8f9f95e2-0b38-4521-83e5-c8e8fea0f5a1"]
}
```